Slow query in Oracle, how to optimize with given subset of IDs
I have a very slow query, not sure how to fix this
SELECT d.I_CUSTOMER_ID
FROM CUSTOMER d
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM CUSTOMER_BACKUP cs
    WHERE cs.I_CUSTOMER_ID = d.I_CUSTOMER_ID
      AND cs.s_status != 'R')
   OR customer_chrg.f_get_backup(d.I_CUSTOMER_ID) = 0;

I already have some IDs that could fit in a IN statement, for example IN (1,2,3,4,10,11) but I am not sure how to narrow the query using an IN statement (if applicable)
The query scans the customer table and retrieves all the ids that either exists on the customer backup table (with status != 'R') OR for all customer executes a slow f_get_backup procedure.
That takes a long time and I am looking for a better solution since I don't want to scan all the table but only a portion of it (IDs that I already have from a client call)

Please post the DDL for your tables in the form of CREATE TABLE statements, and the execution plan for the query. Slow query and That takes a long time are very vague as problem descriptions.

The most likely cause of slowness is the function call in the where clause: customer_chrg.f_get_backup(d.I_CUSTOMER_ID). This is likely to cause a table scan as the optimiser will be unable to utilise indexes. NB: For query optimisations the essential tool is an explain plan.

What happens in this procedure? I doubt you can fix the bad performance as long as you need to call the procedure. You could try to run two separate queries, one for the exists condition, one for the procedure condition. Combine them with UNION ALL. You could also try to self join the table rather than the exists clause because Oracle often likes a JOIN more. But it will likely still be slow due to the procedure.

You said: "...  I don't want to scan all the table but only a portion of it (IDs that I already have from a client call)". Where's that condition in query you posted?

Rewrite as a join:
SELECT d.I_CUSTOMER_ID
FROM CUSTOMER d
LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER_BACKUP cs
  ON cs.I_CUSTOMER_ID = d.I_CUSTOMER_ID
  AND cs.s_status = 'R'
WHERE cs.I_CUSTOMER_ID IS NULL
  OR customer_chrg.f_get_backup(d.I_CUSTOMER_ID) = 0

Note the reversal of the condition (= 'R') and matching where there isn't a joined row (cs.I_CUSTOMER_ID IS NULL)

I would agree with the comment that explain plan would help in understanding why it is running slow.  That said, if you know that the procedure is the slow part, you could use a CASE statement to force the evaluation/filtering of the EXISTS first.  Then the query would only run the procedure for the remaining records.
The other benefit is that using an OR condition would have required you to add the IN to both sides of the OR.  Which can be a little confusing in the beginning.
SELECT d.I_CUSTOMER_ID
  FROM CUSTOMER d
 WHERE d.I_CUSTOMER_ID IN (1,2,3,4,10,11) 
   AND (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                            FROM CUSTOMER_BACKUP cs
                           WHERE cs.I_CUSTOMER_ID = d.I_CUSTOMER_ID
                             AND cs.s_status != 'R')
             THEN 1
             WHEN customer_chrg.f_get_backup(d.I_CUSTOMER_ID) = 0
             THEN 1
             ELSE 0 END) = 1;


SELECT c.i_customer_id
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN customer_backup cb ON c.i_customer_id = cb.i_customer_id
WHERE cb.s_status != 'R'
    OR customer_chrg.f_get_backup(c.i_customer_id) = 0;


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
